# Google Slides API- How to change text color for all shapes of a certain color

Tags: google-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have 11 files with over 140 slides each, and none of the shapes are tied to a theme/master. My goal was the change the master font and also replace all the red text (there is SO much red text) with black text.

I successfully updated the master font (thanks to https://gist.github.com/dsottimano/20a50daded2128b4c86acb430cecba67), but have come up short in trying to write something for ForegoundColor.

I tried to adapt this code and cannot make it work: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/10/changing-the-color-of-all-links-in-google-slides-with-google-apps-script/

I need to replace all text formatted with foregroundcolor hex #e04935 with hex #000000.

Appreciate any tips on making this work!

Here is what I have done so far:

```
//original from: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/10/changing-the-color-of-all-links-in-google-slides-with-google-apps-script/
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
 
function changeTextColorforShapes(){
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  slides.forEach(function(slide) {
    // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getPageElements()
    var elements = slide.getPageElements();
    elements.forEach(function(element){
      // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element#getPageElementType()
      var type = element.getPageElementType();
      // Text boxes are 'SHAPES' (this code doesn't handle table cells)
      if (type == "SHAPE"){
        // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getTextStyle()
        var textStyle = element.asShape().getText().getForegroundColor();
        // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#hasLink()
        // Returns true if text is color #e04935 (https://www.color-hex.com/color/e04935) and changes text to color #ffffff (black)
        if (ForegroundColor('#e04935')
          textStyle.setForegroundColor('#ffffff');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail of `but have come up short in trying to write something for ForegoundColor.` and `I tried to adapt this code and cannot make it work:`? And I cannot understand about `I need to replace all text formatted with foregroundcolor hex #e04935 with hex #000000.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: My slides have red text throughout (all hex #e04935) and I need to change all that text to black. I thought I could use the framework for this code, because it changes the color of all the text with links. I tried this and I have NO IDEA what I am doing:                                                                                              
var textStyle = element.asShape().getText().getForegroundColor();
        if ForegroundColor('#e04935'){
          textStyle.setForegroundColor('#000000');

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is `var textStyle = element.asShape().getText().getForegroundColor(); if ForegroundColor('#e04935'){ textStyle.setForegroundColor('#000000');`? Can you show your current script? If you can do, please add it to your question?

Comment: I added what I have so far to my question. Clearly I have no idea what I am doing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change all the text from `#E04935` to `#000000`, you can try the below snippet:

#### Snippet

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function changeColor() {
   var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
   var slides = presentation.getSlides();
   for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      var elements = slides[i].getPageElements();
      for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++)
         if (elements[j].asShape().getText().getTextStyle().getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString() == '#E04935')
            elements[j].asShape().getText().getTextStyle().setForegroundColor('#000000');

   }
}
```

#### Explanation

The reason your code was not working is because you were trying to use the `getForegroundColor()` method on an object of type `TextRange` while this method is expected to be called from an object of type `TextStyle`.

So in order to test exactly if the color of the text is the wanted one, you will have to retrieve first the color as a RGB color in order to get the HEX value of it.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Editing & Styling Text Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/editing-styling);
- [Apps Script Class TextStyle - getForegroundColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#getforegroundcolor).