# How do you change text colour on an Apps Script in Google Slides? (error Exception: Object is not of type RgbColor. (line 7))

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Basically reiterating the question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860144/how-to-change-a-color-in-google-presentation-using-google-script) that wasn't answered. I tried the method in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252844/google-slides-api-how-to-change-text-color-for-all-shapes-of-a-certain-color) but the same error of

> **Exception: Object is not of type RgbColor. (line 7)**

appears.
Here are the sample slides (it should colour all numbers between 0-3.75, 9-10 in the slide)
[image: the sample slide]

```
r3.forEach(shape => {
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      var elements = slides[i].getPageElements();
      for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++)
         if (elements[j].asShape().getText().getTextStyle().getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString() == '#FFFFFF')
            elements[j].asShape().getText().getTextStyle().setForegroundColor('#FFD700');
```

the error is at line 5, asRgbColor(). I don't know why it doesn't think a shape isn't an object.

Comment: `console.log(elements[j].asShape().getText().getTextStyle().getForegroundColor().getColorType())`

Comment: If you found your answer, consider adding it below as a answer.